# How to add a row to result if a condition based on two adjacent rows is true

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table like this

```
       system_time_start       |        system_time_end        | price 
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------
 2020-11-26 00:59:05.079162-05 | 2020-11-26 23:48:45.030761-05 |  4.35 
 2020-11-26 23:48:45.030761-05 | 2020-11-27 00:26:02.198766-05 | 13.37 
 2020-11-27 00:29:26.116951-05 | 2020-11-27 00:36:22.072045-05 |  4.35 
 2020-11-27 00:36:22.072045-05 | infinity                      | 10.35
```

Is it possible to get this?

```
       system_time_start       | price 
-------------------------------+-------
 2020-11-26 00:59:05.079162-05 |  4.35 
 2020-11-26 23:48:45.030761-05 | 13.37 
 2020-11-27 00:26:02.198766-05 |  null 
 2020-11-27 00:29:26.116951-05 |  4.35 
 2020-11-27 00:36:22.072045-05 | 10.35
```

Right now, I'm post processing the table with a for loop checking if `system_time_start` is not equal to the previous row's `system_time_end`, then insert another row to the result with a null price, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in SQL. I was thinking to use the `lag` function, which can do the check that I want, but inserting a row in between is what I can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `not exists`:

```
select
    system_time_start,
    price
from t
union all
select
    system_time_end,
    null
from t
where
    not exists (
        select
        from t as t2
        where t.system_time_end = t2.system_time_start
    ) and
    system_time_end != 'infinity'
order by system_time_start;
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the `from t t2` syntax? is it a self join?

Comment: @No_name . . . It is really a correlation clause, but `t2` is a name for the table in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks! That was a clever way to think about the problem.